# Use Sqlite database on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, fargate, ecs

I have an application which uses SQLite database and want to migrate it to AWS ECS service. It's dockerized and have access to DB file via mounted volume.

Is there a way to make this work with ECS? (I cannot use EBS as my launch type is `Fargate`). Should I go with something like [EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html) or just get rid of SQLite altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like EFS is now supported on Fargate

- [Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-supports-efs/)
- [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_EFSVolumeConfiguration.html)